i have a lazy row which contains "n" number of boxes. On clicking any box, that box should expand & other box should disappear using smooth animation
Need UI and animation in jetpack compose: i have a lazy row which contains "n" number of boxes. On clicking any box, that box should expand & other box should disappear using smooth animation.
say n= 3.
when 1st box expand- other 2 box should slide out to right side of screen and disappear.
when 2nd box expands- first box should slide out to left of screen and last box should slide out to right side of screen.
now when i am trying to animate using AnimatedVisibility- boxes moves in desired direction, at the same time the clicked box expands. But once the other boxes slides out and disappear, only then the clicked  box moves to left of screen and that transition is not smooth,it feels like a jump movement.

can you share some code that you have tried and also image of how you want it.

I think this is what you are looking for :)
@Composable
fun AnimatedBoxes() {
    var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LaunchedEffect(selectedItem) {
        selectedItem?.let { listState.animateScrollToItem(it) }
    }

    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenHeightDp = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp
    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .animateContentSize(),
        state = listState
    ) {
        // Example for 10 boxes, but you can use a loop for 'n' boxes
        items(10) { index ->
            BoxAnimation(
                screenHeightDp = screenHeightDp,
                index = index,
                isSelected = selectedItem == index,
                isAnySelected = selectedItem != null,
                onClick = {
                    selectedItem = index.takeIf { selectedItem != index }
                },
                centerItem = {
                    scope.launch {
                        listState.animateScrollToItem(index)
                    }
                }
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(20.dp))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BoxAnimation(
    screenHeightDp: Dp,
    index: Int,
    isSelected: Boolean,
    isAnySelected: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    centerItem: () -> Unit
) {
    // This will animate the size change for the selected box
    val size by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = when {
            isSelected -> screenHeightDp
            isAnySelected -> 100.dp
            else -> 100.dp
        },
        finishedListener = {
            if (it == screenHeightDp) centerItem()
        }
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(size, 100.dp)
            .background(Color.Cyan)
            .clickable(onClick = onClick),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = index.toString(), fontSize = 20.sp)
    }
}

